# Assembly code confusion for binary bomb

Tags: c, assembly, gdb, compare, binary-bomb

I am currently trying to finish my binary bomb project. I am currently stuck in the second phase.

I've already checked and found out that the password to defuse this phase of the bomb requires 3 inputs to pass, and that it's comparing them in byte format(so it's checking the characters). My problem is in actually putting in the password. simply put, I'm pretty sure I know the right code to pass, but most of the time it leads me to call the bomb explosion function.

```
08048bab <phase_2>:
8048bab:       55                      push   %ebp
8048bac:       89 e5                   mov    %esp,%ebp
8048bae:       83 ec 08                sub    $0x8,%esp
8048bb1:       8b 45 08                mov    0x8(%ebp),%eax
8048bb4:       80 38 6c                cmpb   $0x6c,(%eax)
8048bb7:       75 0c                   jne    8048bc5 <phase_1+0x1a>
8048bb9:       80 78 01 3c             cmpb   $0x3c,0x1(%eax)
8048bbd:       75 06                   jne    8048bc5 <phase_1+0x1a>
8048bbf:       80 78 02 37             cmpb   $0x37,0x2(%eax)
8048bc3:       74 05                   je     8048bca <phase_1+0x1f>
8048bc5:       e8 3e 02 00 00          call   8048e08 <blow_up_bomb>
8048bca:       c9                      leave
8048bcb:       c3                      ret
```

The values they're comparing in this case(from my knowledge) are the letter 'l', the symbol '<', and the number '7'.

the inputs I tried were:

```
l<7
7<l
7 < l
l < 7
```

I'm pretty confused as it is. What exactly am I doing wrong that is causing the 'bomb' function? Is there another way of writing the input?

Answer (score 0):

> What exactly am I doing wrong that is causing the 'bomb' function?

We can't tell with the info you provided.

*IFF* you call `phase_2` with a pointer to characters `"l<7"`, the bomb will not go off (at least not in `phase_2`, it may still go off somewhere else).

Since you claim to have tried that input, your problem must be somewhere else. Perhaps your input doesn't make it to `phase_2` unmolested?